# Gym changing room, why gym not genitive

Tags: word-usage, possessives, attributive-nouns

In an English study book a task consisted of listening and writing down what you heard. One of the sentences was:

> Fiona and Charlotte met in the gym changing room.

Why is the above correct? The room is not used for changing the gym (dog walking park) so it feels to me that "gym's changing room" or "changing room of the gym" would be more correct. In both of these cases the room is owned or contained in the gym, thus genitive. The first less correct though as the gym is not alive if I am correct.

Comment: I'm not sure.  I would have said *".. the **gym's** changing room"* as your sentence sounds odd to me.

Comment: Is it just a matter of usage? "We met in the station waiting room". "We met in the factory canteen".

Comment: @WeatherVane Right, it could be some kind of compound noun, although these can be idiomatic and vary between dialects and even different people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either would be idiomatic:

> The gym's changing room
>
> The gym changing room

It's like **mall parking lot** or **hospital emergency room**.  It's not a lot with malls parked in it, but a parking lot that is part and parcel of the mall, or a room for hospital emergencies, but a room at the hospital for handling emergencies.